# Identify the components in web

Tags: excel, web, automation

i am on working on company internal webs, unable to share the web
i tried to connect the web with excel vba and send some text into it
however , i am having trouble to identify what is that web components to further explore how i can send text into it

i tried like for example :

```
target.text = "123"
target.value="123"
target.sendkey = "123"
```

all this does not work and i prefer not  to use sendkey

question is :
How i know the one in front end , what is the components . is it a textbox , combobox , listbox , etc etc ?

p.s : the design looks like modern UX design , where it got complicated html structure , yet not seems write by human

Comment: it got some html like input.text if it helps to understand better

Comment: <input class="some class name" required  = true type = "text" , placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy"

how i can send value into this ?